# Renaming LaTeX file to index.tex causes tex4ht to give error when using minitoc

Tags: table-of-contents, tex4ht, minitoc

```
>cat t2.tex
\documentclass[titlepage]{report}%
\usepackage{minitoc}
\begin{document}    
  foo 
\end{document}
```

now

```
htlatex t2.tex "html,4"
```

No errors. Now I name it to `index.tex` and try again:

```
>cp t2.tex index.tex
>htlatex index.tex "html,4"
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
....
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/tex4ht/index.4ht
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \printindex 

l.41 ...name{\the\@nameuse{idxtitle@\@indextype}}}

?
```

any other name seems to work ok

```
cp index.tex indexx.tex
htlatex indexx.tex
```

no errors.  Only when the name is `index.tex`. And this is ONLY when I include `minitoc`. If I remove `minitoc`, then it compiles ok:

```
>cat index.tex
\documentclass[titlepage]{report}%
%\usepackage{minitoc}
\begin{document}
foo 
\end{document}

>htlatex index.tex
```

No error (just need to make sure to remove all old `index.aux` and other `index.*` stuff before trying again. but no error.

So. why is including package `minitoc` causes `tex4ht` error ONLY when the source LaTeX file is called `index.tex`?

specs:

```
>tex4ht -v
tex4ht.c (2009-01-31-07:33 kpathsea)

>latex -v
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)

>uname -a
Linux 3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: For some reason, including `minitoc` causes `tex4ht` to input `index.4ht`, which is when the error happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TeX4ht overloads the LaTeX macros for file input to support configuration files. These files are named with the base name and extension `.4ht`. Package `minitoc` generates and loads a file `\jobname.mtc0`. Thus TeX4ht loads `\jobname.4ht` if this file exists. In case of `\jobname` equals `index` the file `index.4ht` exists, because TeX4ht supports the package `index`. Therefore `index.4ht` assumes that package `index` is loaded, where `\printindex` is defined. Since other packages also might generate such auxiliary files like `minitoc`, the solution would be to avoid job names that are packages or classes, if `htlatex` is used.

Comment: So the cause is the nonstandard extension?

Comment: @egreg The cause is `\input{\jobname.mtc0}` in `minitoc.sty` that triggers `tex4ht` to load `\jobname.4ht`. The extension `.mtc0` does not matter.

Comment: hi, when you say `he solution would be to avoid job names that are packages or classes, if htlatex is used.` So this translates to, in terms new users like me can understand, is to not to use `minitoc` when running tex4ht? OK. Just wanted to make sure I understood.  That is fine. Will do that. I removed minitoc package since I want to always use tex4ht as well.

Comment: @Nasser no, you only need not to give your tex file same name as is the name of some package, because then `tex4ht` includes config file for this package and this may cause some problems.